# Закраска канвы цветом, Android

Tags: android, canvas, камера

Вопрос следующий

1. Получаем канву `Canvas canvas = surfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();`
2. Закрашиваем канву `canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);`
3. Делаем unlock `surfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);`

Экран закрашен и все замечательно, но:

Если сразу после 3го пункта захватить изображение с экрана телефона, по средствам фронтальной камеры и зеркала, мы получаем экран который закрашен, но не полностью.

**Пример фото** : "на квадратики не обращайте внимание", важна лишь степень того на сколько экран зеленный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если после 3го пункта сделать задрежку в 2 секунды, что позволит пропустить N кадров с камеры, то мы получим то что нам необходимо

**Пример фото:** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но проблема в следующем: длительность данной задержки сильно зависит от производительности телефона, разрешения экрана, разрешения фронтальной камеры, и других возможнных факторов.

Грубо говоря на одном устройстве 2 секунд достаточно, на другом нет.
Ставить задержку в 5-8 секунд - не вариант.

**Вопрос:**  как убедиться в том что метод `unlockCanvasAndPost` был выполнен окончательно, и экран телефона действительно полностью зеленого цвета.

Спасибо!

Comment: `canvas.drawColor(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);` - попробуйте так на всякий случай, но проблема скорее всего в другом. Когда уменьшается яркость пикселя - он гаснет не моментально, а за какой-то промежуток времени (в характеристиках дисплеев называется временем отклика). Кроме того есть ещё эффект "засвечивания" (не помню как там его по науке) - чем дольше пиксель светился, тем дольше он приходит в норму. Зависит это всё от технологии самого дисплея и точно угадать время на разных экранах вряд ли получится. Лучше сделать скриншот экрана штатными средствами, если это уместно в рамках задачи.

Comment: к сожалению картинку нужно получить именно с камеры

Comment: А в чём цель - чтобы картинка с экрана получилась без искажений или наоборот скрыть на время снимка то что на экране было? Попробуйте закрасить белым - повлияет ли это на время остаточного эффекта? Если да, то можно попробовать такой трюк: закрасить белым, через некоторую задержку нужным и потом снимок - возможно так общая задержка получится меньше.

Comment: а вы используете "synchronized"?

Comment: нет, но пробовал с ним, тоже не выходило.
Сейчас уже все абсолютно надоело, так как давно не могу решить эту проблему, сделал пропуск 10х кадров, и по мере тестов буду увеличивать если будут появлятся устройства которые не успевают закрасить